# Matching std::index_sequence by default argument

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

Is the following allowed by template argument deduction or is that an undeduced context?

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include<tuple>

template<std::size_t... I>
auto make(std::index_sequence<I...> = std::make_index_sequence<2>())
{
    return;
}

int main() {
    make();
}
```

[Compile warning is pretty weird](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yNZUKZ66bXyzH1Le)

Comment: The compiler warnings tells you that it "deduces" an empty `I...`, thus it cannot convert `std::index_sequence<0, 1>` to `std::index_sequence<>`.

Answer (score 3):

Default arguments are not part of deduction.

So you cannot do what you want here (that way).

If appropriate, you might do:

```
template <typename Seq = std::index_sequence<0, 1>>
auto make(Seq = std::make_index_sequence<2>())
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Not having a pack to expand kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @PasserBy: Forwarding to a helper function (without default) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this compiles:

```
template<std::size_t... I>
auto make(std::index_sequence<I...> = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof... (I)>())
```

but probably doesn't do what you want.